# Как запустить Angularjs проект на сервер nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

Я недавно начал изучать angular.Сделал несколько проектов для себя на angular PhoneGap с сервером api на node express.

Дело в том что angular PhoneGap приложения запускает сам телефон(или сервер на нем,точно не знаю),тоесть я вручную не скармливаю angular какому то серверу... В оф. Документации,а именно в туториале,ангулара,кратко сказано про какой то простой сервер на ноде и все...

Я же просто хочу понять принцип работы...кто кому что скармливает...

Вот допустим есть у меня несколько html страниц,для того чтобы переходя по заданному адресу открывать их,я запущу сервер на ноде (express) которий собственно и будет рендерить ети страницы и отвечать на get и post запросы и тд... тут все понятно.

А как в случае с ангуларом? Правильно ли будет если я,етому же серверу по запросу на определённый адрес буду отдавать `response.render(index)`... index.html ангулара ,к которому собственно все и привязовается в етом фреймворке? Будете ли ето работать вообще?

Или же тут Инной принцип,запускаем простейший http сервер с примера в туториале про ангулар, на своём сервера и все,етого достаточно...,ето релиз...,и таким образом мой angular проект выходит в свет?

Разжуйте пожалуйста,а то на angular вроде как пишу,и expressОМ пользуюсь и модули разные подключаю,но вот куда и как прикрутить мой сайт на ангулар я не знаю (за исключениям PhoneGap).... :(

Answer (score 3):

Работа с angular в вашем сайте ни чем не отличается от работы с ним же на PhoneGap. Вам необходимо добавить в ваши страницы ссылку на angular.js (на локальный файл или файл с CDN, например https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js) и ссылки на файлы ваших скриптов. Удобнее это сделать в каком-либо layout-шаблоне. Все ваши клиентские скрипты (которые работают с angular) должны располагаться в директории `public` (директория по умолчанию для статических файлов). Серверные скрипты не работают с angular ни каким образом, т.к. angular - чисто клиентская библиотека.